# Handling concurrency in hibernate search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

How concurrent access & modification are handled in hibernate search which is based on lucene ?

I am already aware of writer-lock & reader-lock, that a single writer may be open on an index at once. 
And if index is updated once, so in that case reader which was alredy opened NOT able to see changes as they need to close & again open.

What my question is in that case if one reader is already open and then some entity is deleted with lucene index update. So how that reader handeled ? Will it return deleted entity id and tried to open this ?

Comment: what I want if not reopend that reader then what lucene will return for that deleted entity(matched one). whether ignore this or return the entity.

because if it return that ID then there will be incosistency or some exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifecycle of IndexReader and flush operations to IndexWriters are coupled to the user Transactions, but considering that changes you apply to the entity model are made "visible" to full-text queries only after the commit of the current trannsaction.

IndexReader(s) are reopened or refreshed automatically if needed after your previous transaction is committed; in other words it makes sure that after your previous transactions are committed you can find them.

In case a different transaction is applying changes in parallel, yes your current search operation might match elements which have just been deleted but these are transparently removed from the resultset.